# Visual Studio And Github

Tags: visual-studio, github, repository, commit, visual-studio-2022

I don't know what it is, but when I do commit and push with visual studio, these processes are happening with a different user in my Github account. I removed my Github account from Visual Studio and added it again. When I open a new Repository, it opens with my original account, but when I push it, it does it with a different account. can you help thanks

How can I solve this problem

[image: 1]

Comment: You may have something set in your global `.gitconfig`. Try comparing the results of the following commands in the directory containing your git repo:

```git config user.name && git config user.email```

```git config --global user.name && git config --global user.email```

Comment: @Parker I dont Know how ı will do it . can you guide me please

Comment: Open a terminal, navigate to the directory containing your git repository, and run the commands I mentioned above. If the local command has a different output than the `--global` command then you have some rogue values in a `.gitconfig` somewhere in your development path.

Look at [the git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for reference.

Comment: [user]
 name = ----------
 email = mu-------@gmail.com
[merge]
 tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
 prompt = true
[-----------
what ı must change here. Where ı can write my github pass. and username

Comment: `git` and [Github](https://github.com) are two separate things. You don't put your Github creds in your `.gitconfig` file. Look [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) for using ssh keys to auth with Github, or if you use the `https://github.com/{repo}` host, you will be prompted for your email/password each time you push to Github